# How do you create a button in HTML5 that has a link?

Tags: html

I have tried one way to do it:
`<button href='www.google.com'>Google</button>`.
But that didn't work. Can anyone find a solution? I would like to find out how to do this.

Comment: You create a link and then use CSS to style it to resemble a button

Comment: Can you link to the authoritative source on which you are basing your implicit claim that an `href` attribute on a `button` element is valid HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest the button in an anchor:

```html
<a href='https://www.google.com'><button>Google</button></a>
```

Or wrap it in a form (in compliance with the [HTML 5 Specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)):

```html
<form style="display: inline" action="https://www.google.com" method="get">
  <button>Google</button>
</form>
```

Alternatively, you can use JS to attach a `click` event listener that changes `window.location`:

```js
document.querySelector('button').onclick=function(){
  window.location = this.getAttribute('href');
}
```

```html
<button href='https://www.google.com'>Google</button>
```

Comment: Invalid HTML. Button's can't be a child of an anchor

Answer (score 0):

you can create by writing the code like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<button><a href='https://stackoverflow.comcquestions/' target="_blank">Google</a></button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: <button><a href='www.google.com' target="_blank">Google</a></button>

Comment: <a href='www.google.com' target="_blank"><button>Google</button></a>

Answer (score 0):

`button` element hasn't a `href` attribute. You can use a tag instead of a button.
And add a class name to the  tag and you can set a style to the  tag.
If you use bootstrap, please add `btn` class name to the  tag.
Let me know if it works for you or not.

```html
<a href='https://www.google.com' class="btn">Google</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between a button and an anchor tag.

`<a>` - To [navigate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) to other resources. (Hence it has the `href` attribute. Here 'navigate' must be an anchor tag.)

`<button()>` - To perform an action. (Add Comment on this page must be a [button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) tag.)

You should not be mixing them. Use CSS to change your 's styling to look like the button you want.

Following semantic HTML is a good practice, especially for [accessibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Accessibility/What_is_accessibility) reasons.